# Find two 2 x 2 matrices A and B such that the product AB is orthogonal but A and B are not.

Tags: linear-algebra

I already know how to prove that the product of two orthogonal matrices is orthogonal and the product of one orthogonal matrix and one non-orthogonal matrix is orthogonal. But is it possible to find two non-orthogonal matrices such that their product is orthogonal? If it is, how would I go about finding these matrices?

Comment: Hint:  if $A$ is invertible but not orthogonal, $B=A^{-1}$ isn't orthogonal either.

Answer (score 0):

$A = \frac{1}{2}\cdot I_{2\times 2}$ and $B = 2\cdot I_{2\times 2}$

$\det(A) = \frac{1}{4}$ and $\det(b) = 4$ then they are not orthogonal, but $AB = I_{2 \times 2}$ the identity matrix is orthogonal